# Eloquent ORM: Factory not reusing the already created model for a many-to-many relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm modeling and seeding the following models using Laravel 9 and Eloquent:

- Organization (1-n)
- organizations_users (pivot)
- User (1-n)

To seed that model, I followed the documentation and used [`has()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-factories#many-to-many-relationships) and [`recycle()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-factories#recycling-an-existing-model-for-relationships) methods.

##### `database/seeders/DatabaseSeeder.php`

```php
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // Organisations et users
        $organizations = Organization::factory()
            ->count(10)
            ->create();

        $users = User::factory()
            ->recycle($organizations)
            ->has(Organization::factory()->recycle($organizations)->count(1))
            ->count(10)
            ->create();
    }
```

When I run the migration with `->has(Organization::factory()->count(1))`, I'm getting 20 organizations in database instead of 10.

It seems the Organizations are not recycled for the relationships and a new Organization is created for each relationship.

What am I doing wrong? Am I able to seed the relations on a separate call after having seeded the users and the organizations?

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out? I'm stuck in a similar situation. Chaining those requests seems to be failing.

Comment: I ended up creating models without factories but directly with Faker and loops. It is not pretty like in the doc, but it solves the issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use `afterCreating` on `UserFactory` and create random relationship manually.

#### DatabaseSeeder

```php
public function run()
{
    Organization::factory()
        ->count(10)
        ->create();

    User::factory()
        ->count(10)
        ->create();
}
```

#### UserFactory

```php
public function configure()
{
    return $this->afterCreating(function (User $user) {
        $user->organizations()->attach(Organization::all()->random(3));
    });
}
```

Each user will have random 3 organizations that have been created before.